# PHP framework plunge

Tags: php, frameworks, zend-framework

I am about to take plunge into PHP frameworks and my weapon of choice is [kohona](http://kohanaframework.org/).

I have a reasonable amount of OO experince with java. And my javaScript, jQuery, PhP and html/CSS skills are passable. 
Now to the question. Is this a reasonable choice?

As ZEND looks like a steeper learning curve and CakePHP commandline configuration does not immediately strikes me as good way to produce code.

Comment: As someone who has considered PHP, I would recommend Zend only because it allows more freedom with developing an application; I'm not familiar with that Kohana (is that the one that's like an improved CodeIgniter?) but the other major frameworks are too restrictive (understandable since they were trying to imitate Rails), which isn't always a good thing.  ZF, on the other hand, is just a framework and you can do whatever you need to with it.

Comment: @Wayne: Clarification: Zend is more like a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend can have a steep learning curve and the documentation takes some getting used to but if you plan to move into development professionally you should really take the plunge now rather than leaving it.

I can't recall the last contract I had which didn't use Zend.

With Zend it is probably a good idea to read a book before taking the plunge into the docs.

Comment: Thanks for that response, which book(s) do you recommend?

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that Zend Framework is more than just an MVC web framework. It also has a whole range of useful support libraries (DB, serialization, RSS feeds, ...). The documentation isn't always great, but it's the only project I know of with such a wide coverage. It may be worth learning some of the Zend support libraries even if you don't use that as your MVC framework.

Comment: Zend Framework, A Beginner's Guide by Vikram Vaswani is very easy to read and quite up to date. If you just want to see quick examples of everything the Zend way it works.